# C++: Vector value resets efter exiting if-statement

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, 2d-vector

I need to overwrite values in a 2D vector, where the new values is simply just equal to an integer I am counting up. But as soon as I exit this if-statement, the value resets to the original value? I think it may have something to do with the indexing, but I just can't figure it out

So I fill up the vector with either -1 or 0's

```
        vector<vector<int>> P(225, vector<int>(225, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 225; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 225; j++) {

            if (img.at<uchar>(i, j) >= 220) {
                P[i][j] = -1;
            }
            else {
                P[i][j] = 0;

            }
        } 
    }
```

Where

```
img.at<uchar>(i, j)
```

is essentially just an array I check values from, with the same size as the vector. This works fine

Then I go through the vector again, to check for all -1's, and each time if either the vector index above or to the left of [i][j] is 0, I count up integer "bin", which I now want to place as the value on spot [i][j]

```
for (int i = 1; i < 225; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 225; j++) {

           if ((P[i][j - 1] == 0) && (P[i - 1][j] == 0) && P[i][j] == -1) {
                bin++;  
                P[i][j] = bin;
               }
         cout << P[i][j] << endl;
       }

}
```

But right after it exits the if-statement, it just forgets the new value assigned to it? I know the bin integer goes up too, I have printed that out at well, so atleast some of the vector values should be changed, when the specific situation occurs. But they all just go back to 0's and -1's again, as if it never went through the if-statement

I hope my explanation is understandable

Minimalistic test-program: When I run this code that uses basic iostream components, same problem occurs. I think it may be a bug from my side at this point

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using namespace cv;

int main() {

    int bin = 0;

    vector<vector<int>> P(20, vector<int>(20, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

            if (j > 15) {
                P[i][j] = 0;
            }
            if (j <= 14 && j >= 9) {
                P[i][j] = -1;
            }
            if (j < 9) {
                P[i][j] = 0;
            }

            
            

            
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 20; j++) {

            if ((P[i][j-1] == 0) && (P[i-1][j] == 0) && P[i][j] == -1) {
                bin++;
                P[i][j] = bin;
            }
            cout << P[i][j] << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, you print out the new value after the if, and it does not change, even after ensuring that the condition runs? The code provided looks as if it is working, and suggests that the error might lie elsewhere

Comment: Please share a [MCVE]. There isn't an obvious cause for this problem.

Comment: It is a Mat object from the OpenCV library, so img is essentially more of a vector I guess with pixel values on each location

Comment: @Lala5th Yeah, that is correct

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I will get right on that

Comment: @MartinHansen Possibly a waste of time then, but you could try printing out everything at once to see how it is working (or better, step through with a debugger). What I mean is print the value of `bin` and `P[i][j]` before assignement, and `P[i][j]` after assignement as well, still leaving the `cout` shown. Maybe something weird will reveal itself, but unfortunately this is code that looks as if it should work as intended.

Comment: @Lala5th Yeah alright, I will keep on trying. Have updated the post with a bit more simple program that still does not seem to work, but it may very well be a local problem. Thanks though :)

Comment: i changed the sizes in your last code to better see the output and now I dont understand what is the issue with the output. Isnt this what you expect : https://godbolt.org/z/1q9fMz97r ?

Comment: well no it isnt, but your condition is off....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
if ((P[i][j - 1] == 0) && P[i][j] == -1) {
```

you are looking for a `0` that comes before `-1`, but you fill those vectors with `-1` followed by `0`

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
        if (j > 120) {
            P[i][j] = 0;
        }
        if (j < 120) {
            P[i][j] = -1;
        }
```

You assing `-1` to all elements with `j<120` and `0` to elements with `j > 120` (element at `j=120` is already `0`).

This means you have `P[i][119] == -1` and `P[i][120] == 0`:

```
j --->    ... 119 120 ...
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 0 0 0 0
```

Then you try to find an element where `P[i][j - 1] == 0) && P[i][j] == -1)`, ie a `0` followed by a `-1`, but such element does not exist.

You can verify this by using a debugger or by adding some print outs:

```
        if ((P[i][j - 1] == 0) && P[i][j] == -1) {
            std::cout << "this will never be printed, because condition is never true\n";
            bin++;
            P[i][j] = bin;
        }
```